# Бесконечный цикл из-за setState в useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Делаю корзину. Не могу решить проблему бесконечного цикла. Ошибка:

> Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

Пустой массив в конце useEffect решает проблему, но в таком случае таблица не изменяется.

```
  const [cartData, setCartData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
    if (data) {
      const summed = data.reduce((acc, record) => {
        const { name, qty_t, qty_m, price1 } = record;

        if (!acc[name]) acc[name] = { name: '', qty_t: 0, qty_m: 0, price1: 0 };

        acc[name].name = name
        acc[name].qty_t += qty_t;
        acc[name].qty_m += parseInt(qty_m);
        acc[name].price1 += parseInt(price1);

        return acc;
      }, {});

      const new_data = Object.values(summed);

      setCartData(new_data)
    }
  })
```

Comment: Добавьте пустой массив, как второй параметр в юзЕффект. Добавьте отдельную функцию, где обновляете таблицу. При использовании сетКартДата вызывайте ту функцию.

Comment: @entithat а как мне добавить несколько функций? У меня есть функция удаления одного товара и функция удаления всех товаров

Comment: Делаю корзину.... а собственно причем тут хук useEffect? действия с корзиной должно происходить по нажатию пользователя на что то или я не прав?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обновление state вызванное, через setSate вызывает rerender компонента, в этом после rerender-а снова происходит вызов useEffect, в котором setState и снова rerender. И так по кругу. Можно добавить флаг loaded и использовать в useEffect

```
const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)
    useEffect(() => {
        if (loaded) return ;
         //получение data
        setCartData(new_data)
        setLoaded(true)
    }, [loaded])
```

Тогда, если понадобится новая загрузка можно будет устанавливать setLoaded(false) и будет обновление